# Question about ReadyNAS being inaccessible was put on hold as "off-topic" — what to do?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, off-topic

I spent a lot of time reading the rules and requirements, and feel like my question is right in line with Server Fault's regulations for a question.

Can anyone help me out here? I tried to ask for feedback from a moderator, but they just directed me to here.

Link to the post:
[Unable to access ReadyNAS 1100 via web admin portal and SSH](https://serverfault.com/questions/735624/unable-to-access-readynas-1100-via-web-admin-portal-and-ssh)

Comment: With regards to the feedback mechanism you initially chose - we try and keep site-related discussions out of our personal email accounts. Meta exists for exactly this reason, and I'm glad you came and posted your question here.

Comment: It seems to me that the stuff about installing CrashPlan Pro is a bit of a red herring, topic-wise.  Perhaps if the question was edited to be more "how do I use tech support mode to open ports?"--which is the basic gist of your question, yes--it might meet with more favor.  (Editing the post will automatically drop it into the reopen queue.)

Answer (score 19):

Let me start off by first welcoming you to ServerFault.  This community exists for the sole purpose of sharing knowledge and helping each other.  We use the Q/A format to accomplish this goal.

The problem with your question is that it cannot be answered.  Troubleshooting has to take place before you'll arrive to the true question.  I think your initial question is more akin to "How do I troubleshoot this"?  Now, if during your troubleshooting and recovery you hit an error you can ask a question based on that error which could possibly be answered.

You're in a pickle, we all get that, and most of us hopefully sympathize.  However, the way you've asked your question precludes anyone from dropping in and saying "I know the answer!!!  Do this!".  Try to keep the Q/A format in mind, and always ask yourself "can someone answer this without asking me a bunch of questions first?".

To be clear though, I have to side with the moderation action in this case.  Your question, as it is written, is not answerable in the Q/A format.  Try to rethink it, and if you can fix it these same moderators will lift the hold.

Comment: Or consider posting it somewhere else. The internet, and the world in general, has other places. Chat rooms, forums, places suited for this kind of problem!

Answer (score 9):

The close reason I chose is:

> Questions should demonstrate reasonable business information
>   technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported
>   hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be
>   suitable for Server Fault

You installed third-party software in an unsupported fashion, which caused your NAS to break. The outcome, while undesirable, is not all that surprising.

You should contact your manufacturer to see about how to recover.

Comment: Taking advantage of a "tech support mode" on a NAS box to attempt to recover a crashed NAS box, however...

Comment: @MichaelHampton Sure, that's a reasonable usage of Tech Support mode.

Comment: That was meant as a subtle hint that I think you misread (part of) the question. He didn't use the tech support mode to install CrashPlan Pro.

Comment: Ahh, indeed. My bad. I'll revise the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I really can't see what you were expecting of us. You told us you did something and then basically screamed HALP!.

You would be very much better off asking this question of the manufacturer.